# Oracle select from JSON

Tags: json, oracle

How select all name value from this JSON, or how to check that It contains a specific value:

```
{
         "name":"K61_F32_BB_S_NOTEQUALS_DAT_CON",
         "id":3140,
         "process":{
            "type":"ProcessOperatorImpl",
            "operator":"NOT EQUALS",
            "result":true,
            "left":{
               "type":"ProcessData",
               "path":"ns2:sellerName",
               "level":"ns2:sellerName",
               "value":"xyz"
            },
            "right":{
               "type":"ProcessConstant",
               "value":"not you"
            }
         },
         "monitoring":null,
         "monitorSignal":false,
         "outputs":[
            
         ],
         "fired":true
      },
      {
         "name":"K61_F32_BB_S_NOTEQUALS_CON_CON",
         "id":3141,
         "process":{
            "type":"ProcessOperatorImpl",
            "operator":"NOT EQUALS",
            "result":true,
            "left":{
               "type":"ProcessConstant",
               "value":"xyz"
            },
            "right":{
               "type":"ProcessConstant",
               "value":"not you"
            }
         },
         "monitoring":null,
         "monitorSignal":false,
         "outputs":[
            
         ],
         "fired":true
      }
   ]
  }
```

I want to check: input name parameter is included/exists in this json. The number of name values ​​is unknown in advance.

Comment: The JSON you provided is not valid. Please update your question to provide valid JSON.

Comment: Also include which version of Oracle you are using. And preferably what you have tried and what you are stuck on - errors or incorrect results etc.

Comment: You need to check [`JSON_TABLE` function's documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/JSON_TABLE.html#GUID-3C8E63B5-0B94-4E86-A2D3-3D4831B67C62) and describe what is the issue you have with it.